# Theorem of Portmanteau: It suffices to show it for a base?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, weak-convergence

I have a question to the Theorem of Portmenteau,
[see here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures)

Two equivalent statements to $P_n\to P$ weakly, are

(1) $\limsup_n P_n(C)\leq P(C)$ for all closed sets $C$.

(2) $\liminf_n P_n(O)\geq P(O)$ for all open sets $O$.

---

Now suppose that we know that the sets $A_i$ form a base. That is, each open set can be expressed as an union of sets $A_i$.

Would it then suffice to show (2) for the sets $A_i$?

Comment: If the basis is countable, then the answer is yes. Indeed, if $O$ is open and $O'\subset O$ is an element of the basis, then $\liminf_n P_n(O)\geqslant \liminf_n P_n(O')\geqslant P(O')$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: How does your comment show that (2) holds?